# Adding active class to a link keeping his href correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im testing in a menu how to add his active class to the link which is clicked, but when i finished it, the link dont load the content. Without active class, the href load the content correctly.

I supposed that the error is on the PreventDefault but i need the active class with the functional menu.

[EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwOORd)

```
hhhh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a class on an anchor click, but for a *little bit*, just until the anchor start the new page request (in practise you will not notice it).

In order to track which is the 'current' menu, you have to pass the clicked id to the server, and get it back in the newly loaded page. Then set the current class to the specific anchor.

Another approach would be this:

On every page load, check the current url and match with the anchor that holds it. That means this is the current menu --> add the class

**EXAMPLE**

HTML

```
<a class="menu" href="index.php">Home</a>
<a class="menu" href="portfolio.php">Home</a>
...
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var menuAnchor = $('a.menu');
    menuAnchor.removeClass('current');
    menuAnchor.each(function() {
       var that = $(this);
       var menuHref = that.attr('href');
       if (menuHref == url) {
          that.addClass('current');
       }
    });
});
```